# Not an answer reviews - please pay attention in the review queue

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

[CodeCademy Intro to Objects II Trouble finding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207385/codecademy-intro-to-objects-ii-trouble-finding-error/30208077#30208077)

I flagged this yesterday as Not An Answer and it was disputed. Directly from the flagged answer:

> thanks for the help. this is the code as mostly suggested from roin.

This is a reply. A comment. Please take careful note of reviews* - otherwise it becomes a "Why did I fail this review audit?" on meta here in a couple of weeks and degrades Stack Overflow's content.

*Not directed at any one particular user, or group of users.

Comment: Unless my eyes are deceiving me, that's an answer. The OP took the code provided by another answer, altered it and posted a solution.

Comment: So - "thanks for the help, here's my final code" is an answer?

Comment: The thanks could be edited out, but that appears to be different code that what Robin provided.

Comment: Doggone it @bluefeet, that formatting...but we both had the same idea at least. ;)

Comment: @Makoto Feel free to edit it further. But that sure looks to be answer.

Comment: @jdphenix Posting the solution to your problem is in fact an answer, yes.

Comment: Yep, I'm right there with you.  Looks like an answer to me as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an answer that just needed a bit of care and editing.  That user took the other answers and created their own unique solution to the problem.

This should not have been flagged as Not An Answer and the reviewers were correct in disputing the flag.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. It's clear to me now I was off-base in my flag. I'll remember this for future interactions. Thank you again.